# Show that if f : A → Y is Lipschitz then it is uniformly continuous on A

Tags: real-analysis

There's a step that I don't understand from my notes:

Proof.

$\forall\varepsilon>0 \hspace{3pt}\exists\delta>0: \forall x_1,x_2\in A\hspace{3pt}d_X(x_1,x_2)<\delta\hspace{3pt}d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))<\varepsilon$

Choose $\delta=\frac{\epsilon}{L}$

This is the step i don't understand, why am I allowed to choose $\delta$ when delta itself is not arbitrary and it depends by the choose of $\varepsilon$

$d_Y(f(x_1),f(x_2))\leq Ld_x(x_1,x_2)=\frac{L\cdot\varepsilon}{L}=\varepsilon$

Comment: $\delta$ is not supposed to be arbitrary, and it may well depend on $\epsilon$. The point is that it should not depend on $x_1$ and $x_2$.

Comment: Does your definition allow $L=0$?

Comment: No, it says $\exists L>0$ such that...